# Bitbake fails at do_compile in gcc-runtime-5.2.0-r0

Tags: gcc, embedded-linux, raspbian, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to compile a minimal linux distro (rpi-hwup-image) for Raspberry Pi using The Yocto (poky-jethro).
I have tried the process on Xubuntu-15.10 and Ubuntu-Server 14.04 LTS.

Trials on both the OSs have failed in do_compile of gcc-runtime-5.2.0-rev0 with error listed [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15599850/) or [image: here].

undefined referance to `__dso_handle`.

Any ideas ?



--- **updates** ----

I tried the same build on two different PCs, with same OS and almost exactly the same software packages. Both with 8 cores and 8 GB of RAM. There this error didn't arrive on them.
Only happening on my PC and at the exactly same point. I am having 2GB RAM and Core-2-Duo.

Puzzling !!!

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem on my desktop machine and it is Core-2 Duo with 4 GB ram. I tried to do clean and just bitbake gcc-runtime too and that didn't help. Did you find any solid reason that it is happening on low end machines ? any help on this is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please follow my answer..

Comment: Thank you. Yes even my drive was with NTFS partition. I will try that tomorrow and will let you know the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out what was wrong with my compilation.
I was trying to do the build on an NTFS partition, **which was messing things up** !!! d'oh!!
I retried the process on the same PC on an ext4 drive and it ran smooth.

Comment: Thank you this worked fine for me. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

your compilation breakage. because of unable to find essential native library on your host machine for the yocto compilation.

Before compilation of the Image.you have to prepare host for the yocto environment.
follow the steps mention on Yocto Project Quick Start :
http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/yocto-project-qs/yocto-project-qs.html

Thank you.
Best Regards,
Kanji Viroja.

Comment: I have already followed this these steps, and compiled a core-minimal image successfully on a server machine as host, but for some reason, it's not happenning on my laptop

Comment: Hi Rishav,
        You can try this:
        export ARCH=arm
        export PATH=~/gcc-linaro/bin/:$PATH // your toolchain path
        export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- // *T&C
       Thanks,
       Best Regards,
       Kanji Viroja.

Comment: Install necessary Packages : http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/board-support-package/openembedded-%28core%29

Comment: If above solution doesn't work then try this : clean downloaded package and tmp folder then start compilation from the scratch.